# WPF-Show ToolTip On ListGridview with Custom Style

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, tooltip

I am New in WPF.  I have used listview in my application below is XAML:-

```
<ListView x:Name="lstviewMeters"  Grid.Row="2" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MeterRowStyle}"   Height="260" Margin="0,73,31,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="597" AlternationCount="2" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView >
                    <GridViewColumn   Header="Feeder" Width="125" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MeterName}" >
                        <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                                    <TextBlock Text="Feeder" Padding="9,4,3,3"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MeterID}">
                        <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                                    <TextBlock Text="ID" Padding="9,4,3,3"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
  </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Now I want to Show ToolTip On Each Cell Of ListviewGridview. What is best way to Show Custom Style ToolTip On cell. I googled but not getting proper solution for the same 
Is there any solutionfor the same

Answer (score 3):

Create CellTemplate then add tooltip to TextBlock

```
    <ListView x:Name="lstviewMeters"  Grid.Row="2" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MeterRowStyle}"   Height="260" Margin="0,73,31,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="597" AlternationCount="2" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView >
                <GridViewColumn   Header="Feeder" Width="125">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MeterName}" ToolTip="{Binding MeterName}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                                <TextBlock Text="Feeder" Padding="9,4,3,3"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="120">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MeterID}" ToolTip="{Binding MeterID}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                                <TextBlock Text="ID" Padding="9,4,3,3"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```